# Pass non numeric arguement and return a non numeric value from a shell function

Tags: bash, shell, sh

```
test_function()           
{                
var=$1          
echo "**$var**" 
var2="bb 6"    
return $var2     
}                

return_val=`test_function "aa 3" `
echo $return_val
```

I need to pass non numeric character to a function and return a non numeric value from a function.
Above code is failing. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
function test_function()           
{                
var=$1          
echo "**$var**" 
var2="bb 6"    
echo $var2     
}                

return_val=$( test_function "aa 3" )
echo $return_val
```

Comment: Yes and than how do you capture your result inside a variable when you execute the function?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval` command to return value to an argument `output`

```
test_function()
{
    input=$1;
    echo "**$input**"
    var_out="bb 6" 

    eval "$2=\"$var_out\""
}

test_function "This is input" output 

echo $output;
```

Comment: Yes and than how do you capture your result inside a variable when you execute the function?

Answer (score 0):

return is used to return the function status code, it must be followed by an integer
after calling the function, you can use $? to get the status code

```
$ help return
return: return [n]
    Return from a shell function.

    Causes a function or sourced script to exit with the return value
    specified by N.  If N is omitted, the return status is that of the
    last command executed within the function or script.

    Exit Status:
    Returns N, or failure if the shell is not executing a function or script.
```

if you want to get the value of var2, you should use `echo $var2` instead of `return $var2`

Comment: Yes and than how do you capture your result inside a variable when you execute the function?